# How to enforce updated proguard rule on android app update?

Tags: android, proguard

I have an app with initial version having proguard rule .

```
      minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

After the app release to play store, I found that some of the proguard rules are missing, so I update the proguard rules with new rules.

While testing,  I found that app update is not enforcing the updated proguard rule . Once I uninstall / install (fresh install) app then the updated proguard rule started getting effective.

Also if I delete the app user data then also the new proguard rule was effective.

Question : Is there any specific instruction to be followed to apply the updated proguard rule on app update?

I tried app update with updated proguard rule . It did not work.

On fresh install updated proguard rule was effective.